# js how to return inner layer Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following nested Promise object. what I need is to return the `res3` to other then function. When I use the follwing code, I got return as `res1` but not `res3`. What should I do to get `res3`?

The thought of me is that I need post data to `/pc_data/` , and if post success I need to post to `/server/register_keystroke/`, then I need to get the `res3` for following purpose.

Thank you!

```
registerKeystroke() {
        return this._sendRequest('/pc_data/', {'username': username, 'password': password})
        .then(res1 => {
            console.log('res1:' + res1);
            this._change_status(res.toString());
            return res1
        })
        .then(
            this._sendRequest('/server/register_keystroke/', this._getRequestData())
                .then(res3 => {
                    this._clearInputsTimestamps();
                    console.log('res3:' + res3);
                    return res3;
                })
        )}

_sendRequest(url, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        $.post(
            url,
            JSON.stringify(data),
            (data) => resolve(data),
            'json'
        );
    })
}
```

Comment: Promises auto-flatten. Just add return statements e.g. `return this._sendRequest`

Answer (score 1):

```
 .then( this._sendRequest("..."))
```

That makes no sense as you pass the promise that your request utility returns as a callback to the then handler, and calling a promise does not work. Imstead you should pass a handler function that returns a Promise, so the outer promise chain will be flattened and you get what you want:

```
 .then(() => this._sendRequest("..."))
 .then(response => /*..*/)
```

Oh and a closing bracket (`}`) is at the wrong position.

Comment: thank you. But what I want to return is the value of execution status of `this._sendRequest('/server/register_keystroke/', this._getRequestData())`, So would you mind write the code of this purpose?

Comment: @jeffrey thats what this does.

Comment: Thank you! This really help me!